# Impala Shell query -q with double quotes in string

Tags: shell, putty, double-quotes, impala, plink

I am generating a text file which is being used by plink to use the impala shell and run an insert statement using -q. Currently using dummy data from Wikipedia to make sure it has no errors before I use it in anger.

This is working fine in pretty much all instances except for the following (I've changed some bits but the result is the same):

```
impala-shell -c -k -q "INSERT INTO TABLE imaginarydatabasename.T_Test
VALUES
('Bob','Monkhouse','1928-06-01',2003,'An expert on the history of silent cinema and a film collector, Monkhouse presented Mad Movies in 1966. He wrote, produced, financed and syndicated the show worldwide. The show featured clips from comic silent films, many from his own private collection, some of which he had helped to recover and restore. This film collection was the cause of a court case at the Old Bailey in 1979. Having loaned Terry Wogan\'s son a film, Monkhouse was charged with attempting to defraud film distributors of royalties, but after two years the judge decided that there was no case to answer.[8] Many of the films in his collection were seized and not returned to Monkhouse.[9] In 2008, the British Film Institute was contacted by Monkhouse\'s daughter, Abigail, who asked if they would like to view the collection and provide some advice as to the best way of preserving it. Amongst the discoveries were many radio and TV shows long thought lost. Dick Fiddy, the archivist, said \"It\'s a huge, unwieldy collection which deals with a number of areas. It\'s not just film and TV. Initially, we found half a dozen TV shows that we knew to be missing.\" Amongst those shows rediscovered were many that feature Monkhouse himself, including The Flip Side, a 1966 play in which he starred as a television DJ with his own late night show, and the 1957/58 series of his comedy My Pal Bob including an episode in which he is suspected of an extramarital affair.[10] The archive consisted of 36,000 videotapes, going back to when Monkhouse first bought a home video recorder in 1966. His film archive began in the late 1950s. The entire Monkhouse film and television archive is now held by Kaleidoscope, including all the material previously held by the NFTVA. It was catalogued and restored to digital formats for a major event at Bafta on 24 October 2009. Chris Perry, of Kaleidoscope and Kaleidoscope Publishing, said: \"We are painstakingly transferring the important contents of the video tapes and restoring radio shows. There are many incredible finds, and the event [is] an exciting time for all concerned.\" In his final years, Monkhouse hosted a show on BBC Radio 2 called The Monkhouse Archive, in which he provided humorous links to clips of comedy acts spanning the previous 50 years.',1,2.5,'2016-06-21 14:41:25');" -i impala-server.com;
```

If I copy the part inside the outer double quotes (what is being run by q), paste it into hue and execute it I have no problems.

What I believe is happening is that the double-quotes in the 5th column is telling the -q part of the shell that the query text has ended.

How do I tell the shell that the double-quotes aren't ending it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the \

You have to do it not once, not twice but three times as follows:

```
impala-shell -c -k -q "INSERT INTO TABLE database.table
VALUES
('Bob','Monkhouse','1928-06-01',2003,'see if I can get \\\ to work...',1,2.5,'2016-06-21 14:41:25');" -i impala-server;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to test it would be to run a straight select statement instead of the insert to see if impala shell is able to execute the query. See an example below from your code. I was able to execute it without any issues, but then if i got rid of any of the escape characters it would error out, so i don't think the double quotes are causing the issue.

```
impala-shell -i impala-server.com -c -k -q "select 'Bob','Monkhouse','1928-06-01',2003,'An expert on the history of silent cinema and a film collector, Monkhouse presented Mad Movies in 1966. He wrote, produced, financed and syndicated the show worldwide. The show featured clips from comic silent films, many from his own private collection, some of which he had helped to recover and restore. This film collection was the cause of a court case at the Old Bailey in 1979. Having loaned Terry Wogan\'s son a film, Monkhouse was charged with attempting to defraud film distributors of royalties, but after two years the judge decided that there was no case to answer.[8] Many of the films in his collection were seized and not returned to Monkhouse.[9] In 2008, the British Film Institute was contacted by Monkhouse\'s daughter, Abigail, who asked if they would like to view the collection and provide some advice as to the best way of preserving it. Amongst the discoveries were many radio and TV shows long thought lost. Dick Fiddy, the archivist, said \"It\'s a huge, unwieldy collection which deals with a number of areas. It\'s not just film and TV. Initially, we found half a dozen TV shows that we knew to be missing.\" Amongst those shows rediscovered were many that feature Monkhouse himself, including The Flip Side, a 1966 play in which he starred as a television DJ with his own late night show, and the 1957/58 series of his comedy My Pal Bob including an episode in which he is suspected of an extramarital affair.[10] The archive consisted of 36,000 videotapes, going back to when Monkhouse first bought a home video recorder in 1966. His film archive began in the late 1950s. The entire Monkhouse film and television archive is now held by Kaleidoscope, including all the material previously held by the NFTVA. It was catalogued and restored to digital formats for a major event at Bafta on 24 October 2009. Chris Perry, of Kaleidoscope and Kaleidoscope Publishing, said: \"We are painstakingly transferring the important contents of the video tapes and restoring radio shows. There are many incredible finds, and the event [is] an exciting time for all concerned.\" In his final years, Monkhouse hosted a show on BBC Radio 2 called The Monkhouse Archive, in which he provided humorous links to clips of comedy acts spanning the previous 50 years.',1,2.5,'2016-06-21 14:41:25'"
```

Comment: True, as the following was quite happy:

`impala-shell -c -k -q "select *, '\"Mr\" Bob\'s workshop' AS testthing from database.table" -B -o "Test.txt" --output_delimiter='|' --print_header -i impala-server;`

Maybe it's the square brackets or other things in the original string. I'll have to use trial & error and see what's causing the issue.